# C# Writing to XML file does not save object

Tags: c#, xml, file, object, save

I have some experience in Java. Today I started programming in C# because I like Visual Studio.

As an exercise i'm building a system that manages all employees in a company. 
Im working on a class called `Function`:

```
public class Function
{

    private String functionname;
    private String department;
    private double hourpay;


    public String getFunc()
    {
        return functionname;
    }

    public String getDepartement()
    {
        return department;

    }

    public double getPay()
    {
        return hourpay;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return ("Function: " + functionname + "\n" + "Department: " + department + "\n" + "Hourly Pay: " + hourpay);
    }

    public void setFunctionName(string functionname)
    {
        this.functionname = functionname;

    }

    public void setDepartment(String department)
    {
        this.department = department;

    }

    public void setPay(double pay)
    {
        this.hourpay = pay;
    }
```

A very simple basic class to model a function, Now I would like to save functions in a XML file.

What I have in mind is:
After I created a function I put it in a list called Functions (List functions)
I write the list to an XML file.

If I want to update the XML file I simply load the List, add a new function, and then overwrite it to the XML file.

I made my class functions like this;

```
public class Functions{

    public List<Function> functions = new List<Function>();

    public void addFunction(Function func){
        functions.Add(func);

    }

    public void writeFunctions()
    {
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer writer =
                new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Functions));
            System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(
             @"C:\CDatabase\Functions.xml");
            writer.Serialize(file, this);
            file.Close();
    }

}
```

To test it I implemented this in a click event of a button:

```
Function programmer = new Function();
schoonmaker.setFunctionName("Programmer");
schoonmaker.setDepartment("IT");
schoonmaker.setPay(16.50);
FunctionDatabase.addFunction(schoonmaker);
FunctionDatabase.writeFunctions();
```

It creates the XML file(If its not there), and this is in the XML file:

```
<Functions xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <functions>
    <Function />
  </functions>
</Functions>
```

Its empty, and I dont understand why and how to fix it.

I think i'm thinking too easy, but I cant find a fix.

Thanks in advance,

Chris

Comment: What is schoonmaker?

Comment: `c# != java`, Have you tried to find a few samples about how xml serialization is done in c# before posting this question? Hint: search for `c# xml serialization` :)

Comment: Your Function class need properties.

Comment: public members (properties and fields) will be serialized. In xml serialization they'll become tags. you can be explicit with the serialization of a class by implementing `ISerializable` and explicitly work the StreamingContext and SerializationInfo object.

Comment: see the special constuctor for deserialization as well: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 4):

C# doesn't use getter and setter methods like Java. Create your properties like this:

```
private string functionname;

public string functionname
{
  get { return functionname; }
  set { functionname = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A suggestion would be to use properties instead of getter/setter functions - they are a feature of C# which are used a lot.

For example, instead of:

```
public double getPay()
{
    return hourpay;
}
```

Try:

```
public double HourPay { get; set; }
```

Or if you want to be able to perform actions within the getter/setter:

```
private double hourPay;
public double HourPay
{
    get
    {
        return hourPay;
    }
    set
    {
        hourPay = value;
    }
}
```

By using public properties in this way, the XML serializer should generate the file you were expecting.